# replace parent div from its div child

Tags: javascript, html

I need for help, how to change parent div from each child div i have html like bellow

```
<div id="parent1">
    <div class="toParent3">
    </div>

    <div class="toParent2">
    </div>

    <div class="toParent4">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="parent2">
     //content
</div>

<div id="parent3">
     //content
</div>
```

i want to do ,when the first load i wanna show only #parent1 and its child, and then when child's #parent1 is clicked, I want to change whole #parent1 to #parent2 and hide all div except #parent2

Answer (score 0):

You can use append, this code is only for parent2 as per your example.

```js
$('.toParent2').click(function(){
   $('.parent2').append($('.toParent2'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent1">
    <div class="toParent3">
      Child to parent 3
    </div>

    <div class="toParent2">
      Child to parent 2
    </div>

    <div class="toParent4">
      Child to parent 4
    </div>
</div>

<div class="parent2">
     //content
</div>

<div class="parent3">
     //content
</div>
```

Comment: verry good @sudhir kumar, but i think i was not complete to ask my question, acctually I want to do when the first load i wanna show only #parent1 and its child, and then when div child is clicked, I want to change whole #parent1 to #parent2 and hide all div except #parent2

Answer (score 0):

here's a vanilla js solution that is a bit more generic.

```js
let all = document.getElementsByClassName('movable');

function hideParents() {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('_parent_'), (e) => {
    e.classList.add('hidden');
  });
}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('toParent1'), (e) => {
  console.log('lols', e.addEventListener);
  e.addEventListener('click', () => {
    hideParents();
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(all, (e2) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const p = document.getElementById('parent1');
        p.appendChild(e2);
        p.classList.remove('hidden');
      });
    });
  });
});

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('toParent2'), (e) => {
  e.addEventListener('click', () => {
    hideParents();
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(all, (e2) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const p = document.getElementById('parent2');
        p.appendChild(e2);
        p.classList.remove('hidden');
      });
    });
  });
});

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('toParent3'), (e) => {
  e.addEventListener('click', () => {
    hideParents();
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(all, (e2) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const p = document.getElementById('parent3');
        p.appendChild(e2);
        p.classList.remove('hidden');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
._parent_.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="_parent_" id="parent1">
  I'm parent1
    <div class="movable toParent3">To3
    </div>

    <div class="movable toParent2">To2
    </div>

    <div class="movable toParent1">To1
    </div>
</div>

<div class="_parent_ hidden" id="parent2">
     I'm parent2
</div>

<div class="_parent_ hidden" id="parent3">
     I'm parent3
</div>
```

not that removing `setTimeout()` there's a glitch happening, the elements are moved correctly but the DOM is refreshed too early

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/nvm05dbm/)'s another solution, that replaces the text of the parent instead of moving the children.

Comment: thanks for your response,, its so great i think i was not complete to ask my question. when the first load i wanna show only #parent1 and its child, and then when div child is clicked, I want to change whole #parent1 to #parent2 and hide all div except #parent2

Comment: what about just changing the text/content/style of the parent, probably would be a better solution (for big numbers, even in terms of performances)

Comment: could you give me an example code, cz im new with this